# how to replace charactor including double quote?

Tags: java, regex

I have a tag like following, I want to replace the USERNAME in this, here user name is dynamic value:

```
<ns3:AgentName xmlns:ns3="http://example.com">USERNAME</ns3:AgentName>
```

I want to replace this tag with

```
<ns3:AgentName>XXXXXXX</ns3:AgentName>
```

I tried the regex like following:

```
<ns3:AgentName.*</ns3:AgentName>
<ns3:AgentName xmlns:ns3="http://example.com">.*</ns3:AgentName>
```

Nothing worked for me

Comment: I don't see the regex you tried. And where are the double quotes your title refers to?

Comment: @lurker good old markup, intrepreting tags when they are not formatted as code ;)

Comment: Try using 2 capturing groups `(<ns3:AgentName xmlns:ns3="http://example\.com">).*?(</ns3:AgentName>)` and replace with `$1XXXXXXX$2` See https://regex101.com/r/5ZElS8/1

Comment: this also not working, I'm using str.replace("abc","xyz") method in java

Comment: @Pavankant See for example this [demo](https://ideone.com/vKBwGl)

Comment: Did you try using lookahead and lookbehind? `(?<=<ns3:AgentName)(.*)(?=<)` - Does this solve your problem?

Comment: this is working for me

Comment: if i use str.replace("(<ns3:AgentName xmlns:ns3=\"http://example\\.com\">).*?(</ns3:AgentName>)", "$1XXXXXXX$2")  then it doesn't works

Comment: @Thefourthbird solution works fine for me thanks

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when I tested it at [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html).

My regular expression was:

```
(\<ns3:AgentName) xmlns:ns3="http://example.com"(\>).*(\</ns3:AgentName\>)
```

If you want to replace USERNAME with x's, my replacement was:

```
$1$2xxxxxx$3
```

If you want to put USERNAME in the replacement, I'd make my regular expression this:

```
(\<ns3:AgentName) xmlns:ns3="http://example.com"(\>.*)(\</ns3:AgentName\>)
```

and my replacement this:

```
$1$2$3
```